# How to remove a Mercurial commit that has been pushed?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I have a system that is in a bitbucket repository, I uploaded it with Mercurial.

I had a problem a few days ago of uploading a document that I should not have touched. Now I want to know if there is a command option to remove the commit I made.

Of course I tried with `hg log -l 5` and then `hg strip 'id commit'`, but I do not want to go back to a previous point, if not delete the commit. To be more precise, the last one.

**Note for expert!** only: Remember I have already pushed my commit to bitbucket

Comment: I assume by "upload" you mean that you pushed the changes.

Comment: That's right, I've already uploaded it and it's in the cloud. But now I want to delete that commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to "remove the commit" is by stripping it on bitbucket, but that has several disadvantages, especially if someone besides you has already "pulled" the offending commit.

The preferred way to handle your situation is to use `hg backout`.  This "hides" the commit, rather than actually removing it.

Comment: This is the right approach. If and only if there are only a very small copies of the repository (eg on Bitbucket, your local PC, and maybe nowhere slse) would the option to strip be feasible, in which case you have to strip the invalid commit in every location at about the same time.